# Unable to click on element inside an iframe using cypress iframe plugin

Tags: javascript, typescript, iframe, cypress, mocha.js

I am trying to automate add to cart and checkout scenario in a website, in this process we have to click on proceed button which is inside an iframe I have tried several approaches including use of cypress-iframe plugin however I am getting different error each time I run and still not able to click on "Proceed" button inside the iframe [image: Proceed button html image]

Please find code for first approach using iframe-plugin below:-

```
 it('Nykaa test', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.nykaa.com/'); 
    cy.get('input.css-1upamjb').type('Facewash{enter}'); 
    cy.get('div#product-list-wrap').should('exist'); 
    cy.get('#product-list-wrap a').first().invoke('removeAttr','target').click(); 
    cy.wait(1000);
    cy.contains("Add to Bag").click();
    cy.get("button>span.cart-count").click();
    cy.frameLoaded("div>iframe[src*='mobileCart']");
    cy.iframe("div[data-test-id='footer'] button").should('be.visible').click({force:true});
});
```

Please find the code for second approach without using plugin below:-

```
it('Nykaa test', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.nykaa.com/'); 
    cy.get('input.css-1upamjb').type('Facewash{enter}'); 
    cy.get('div#product-list-wrap').should('exist'); 
    cy.get('#product-list-wrap a').first().invoke('removeAttr','target').click(); 
    cy.wait(1000);
    cy.contains("Add to Bag").click();
    cy.get("button>span.cart-count").click();
    const proceedIFrame=cy.get("div>iframe[src*='mobileCart']").its('0.contentDocument.body').should('be.visible').then(cy.wrap);
    proceedIFrame.get("div[data-test-id='footer'] button").should('be.visible').click();
   });
```

upon running code using both of these approaches I am getting following different errors below:-

[image: Error1]

[image: Error2]